# How to get the according generated javascript file for a KotlinJS project dependencies?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Previously I use the IDEA built-in system to build my kotlinJs project. Today when I migrate it to use the official gradle kotlin2js plugin.

I met a problem.

Previously, I can get the generated libs file like `kotlin.js` and `kotlinx-html-js.js`.

But now it seems that I can't get them even when use the `buildDependents` gradle task.

How to get them?

Or even better, how to bundle them together like the Webpack?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I know is to use JS DCE plugin with "development mode" enabled: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/javascript-dce.html#development-mode

Alternatively you could create a Copy task, which looks at the dependencies, and extracts .js files from those (look for `task assembleWeb` in the tutorial: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html)